John the Ripper - Why is the hash file including file names and should they be there?
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, installed via snap.
When I run the command, after setting up alias, 'john2rar Yes.rar > rar.hashes' the rar.hashes file contents become this:
Yes.rar:$RAR3$*1*cf58ea337ee6642c*1b7b4ef5*48*35*1*20988a3157731dde4e3a3505d22058c26cbea927a6bf97c7258532e33e495063c5f96324b91b44ce5202734f30bb3f4b*33:1::Yes\1279087209773.jpg Yes\1296715670153.jpg Yes\4chan\10 15 16.png Yes\4chan\1237702186979.jpg Yes\4chan\1238257913513.jpg Yes\4chan\1247722749512.png Yes\4chan\1249983505316.jpg Yes\4chan\1251775301121.png Yes\4chan\1252374762581.jpg Yes\4chan\1253671143741.jpg Yes\4chan\1253762200355.jpg Yes\4chan\1253762689997.jpg Yes\4chan\1254025988072.jpg Yes\4chan\1257897533903.jpg Yes\4chan\1259981104459.jpg Yes\4chan\1268511118287.jpg Yes\4chan\1268513505025.jpg Yes\4chan\1268628751045.png Yes\4chan\1269111897360.jpg Yes\4chan\1269574061825.jpg Yes\4chan\1269574599796.jpg Yes\4chan\1270448162598.jpg Yes\4chan\1270814005843.jpg Yes\4chan\1272505664374.jpg Yes\4chan\1272679448367.jpg Yes\4chan\1273362739426.jpg Yes\4chan\1273945625768.jpg Yes\4chan\1273945704399.jpg Yes\4chan\1273945741530.jpg Yes\4chan\1273952537942.jpg Yes\4chan\1274833104616.gif Yes\4chan\1275010602517.jpg Yes\4chan\17.jpg Yes\4chan\1826 x's.pn

Should I manually modify this file to remove the file names for the next step of running john rar.hashes? Or is somehow the file names part of the hashes? Why does it abruptly end at ".pn" instead of a full .png?
If I remove the file names, should I be leaving the colons, so the file ends in b*33:1::? Should I remove the first prefix of Yes.rar:? I can find few examples of what I should be expecting. This is the closest with it including the contents of their hash file: https://dfir.science/2014/07/how-to-cracking-zip-and-rar-protected.html
../test.zip:$pkzip$2*2*1*0*0*1b*a80c*95e4e9547dcfcde4b8b2f05a80aaeb9d15dd76e7526b81803c8bf7*2*0*1b*f*72051312*0*44*0*1b*a808*cbafdd390bf49ea54064ab3ff9f486e6260b9854e37d1ee3a41c54*$/pkzip$
But I don't have it terminating with $/pkzip$; I'd almost expect we'd want it to terminate with $/RAR3$. Should I actually have a hash file that contains the entirety of the directory of files with that terminating string?
I want to make sure my hash file is sensible prior to wasting cpu cycles on cracking it. The rar archive is multiple Gigabytes.
